# How to create distinct count from queries with several tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create one single query that will give me a distinct count for both the ActivityID and the CommentID. My query in MS Access looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Category.Category, Count(tbl_Activity.ActivityID) AS CountOfActivityID, 
    Count(tbl_Comments.CommentID) AS CountOfCommentID
FROM tbl_Category LEFT JOIN 
    (tbl_Activity LEFT JOIN tbl_Comments ON 
        tbl_Activity.ActivityID = tbl_Comments.ActivityID) ON 
        tbl_Category.CategoryID = tbl_Activity.CategoryID
WHERE 
    (((tbl_Activity.UnitID)=5) AND ((tbl_Comments.PeriodID)=1))
GROUP BY 
    tbl_Category.Category;
```

I know the answer must somehow include `SELECT DISTINCT` but am not able to get it to work. Do I need to create multiple subqueries?

Answer (score 1):

This is really painful in MS Access.  I think the following does what you want to do:

```
SELECT ac.Category, ac.num_activities, aco.num_comments
FROM (SELECT ca.category, COUNT(*) as num_activities
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.Category, a.ActivityID
            FROM (tbl_Category as c INNER JOIN
                  tbl_Activity as a
                  ON c.CategoryID = a.CategoryID 
                 ) INNER JOIN
                 tbl_Comments as co
                 ON a.ActivityID = co.ActivityID
            WHERE a.UnitID = 5 AND co.PeriodID = 1
           ) as caa
      GROUP BY ca.category
     ) as ca LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.Category, COUNT(*) as num_comments
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.Category, co.CommentId
            FROM (tbl_Category as c INNER JOIN
                  tbl_Activity as a
                  ON c.CategoryID = a.CategoryID
                 ) INNER JOIN
                 tbl_Comments as co
                 ON a.ActivityID = co.ActivityID
            WHERE a.UnitID = 5 AND co.PeriodID = 1
           ) as aco
      GROUP BY c.Category
     ) as aco
     ON aco.CommentId = ac.CommentId
```

Note that your `LEFT JOIN`s are superfluous because the `WHERE` clause turns them into `INNER JOIN`s.  This adjusts the logic for that purpose.  The filtering is also very tricky, because it uses *both* tables, requiring that both subqueries have both `JOIN`s.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error in the JOIN OPERATION.

Comment: So you are saying that I need to essentially do two subqueries, each filtered for the same criteria, but i can only do one distinct count at a time? Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: @rohrl77 . . . Yes, that is what this is saying.  I found two syntax errors -- missing `as` and `GROUP BY` in the wrong place.  But nothing regarding the `JOIN`s pops out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Category.Category, Count(DISTINCT tbl_Activity.ActivityID) AS CountOfActivityID, 
    Count(DISTINCT tbl_Comments.CommentID) AS CountOfCommentID
FROM tbl_Category LEFT JOIN 
    (tbl_Activity LEFT JOIN tbl_Comments ON 
        tbl_Activity.ActivityID = tbl_Comments.ActivityID) ON 
        tbl_Category.CategoryID = tbl_Activity.CategoryID
WHERE 
    (((tbl_Activity.UnitID)=5) AND ((tbl_Comments.PeriodID)=1))
GROUP BY 
    tbl_Category.Category;
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `Count(DISTINCT` in Access SQL...

Comment: @rohrl77, Oh sorry then, I always fall into trap of thinking access has some compatibility with ANSI. I would suggest then using a database instead of access.

Comment: @rohrl77, maybe you could use SQLite in memory mode to at least have an ANSI compatible database at hand (I have done that in the past from within VBA in Excel). IMHO no serious data work should use access anyway.

Comment: @ErikA, "access SQL" :) Wish it had some basic ANSI SQL compatibility.

Comment: @CetinBasoz That is an interesting solution. Unfortunately, the technology I'm using is dictated by the already developed application. How would I go about incorporating an SQLLite DB through VBA? Is it preinstalled on Windows? If not, I'm back to square one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227836/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-rohrl77).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Access actually has an ANSI compatibility mode, and is remarkably more compatible with ANSI 89 and 92 than SQLite is (for example, Access does support `RIGHT JOIN` and all the weird ANSI type names)

Comment: @ErikA, wow access supports right join!!!! What an important JOIN to support. Wish it had support for basics rather than items that would be used once in a thousand years. It doesn't support simple inner join with more than one table unless peculiar parentheses are used but supports right :) Super.